# Using generics to find a View by Class

Tags: java, android

This works but feels clunky - any suggestions for improvement?

```
public static <T extends View> T findViewByClassReference(View rootView, Class<T> classReference){
  if(classReference.isInstance(rootView)){
    return classReference.cast(rootView);
  }
  if(rootView instanceof ViewGroup){
    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) rootView;
    for(int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++){
      View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
      View match = findViewByClassReference(child, classReference);
      if(match != null){
        return classReference.cast(match);
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This works but feels clunky

This seems fine. It does the job well. I don't see how this can be done simpler, and I'm not aware of other existing method in the SDK that can help simplify this.

> any suggestions for improvement?

I have only minor suggestions:

- The method uses depth first search to find a view. Depending on the actual tree of views in the application, this might be slow, for example when you have very deep trees but the class you're looking for is at a shallow level. In such case a breadth first search would perform better. This is not something to "fix", just something to keep in mind, and adjust to your actual application as necessary
- Another point to keep in mind is that the method will return the first view with matching class. When there are multiple views of the same class, a user might not get the one expected
- As with any utility method, it's good to add a nice javadoc. That will be a good place to mention about the previous points (search algorithm used, returns first match).
- A common name for `Class` instances is `clazz`. I suggest to use that name to make the code look more familiar to other developers, and it's shorter too than `classReference`
- The "ByClassReference" in the method name is redundant, because this is implied by the method signature
- The formatting could be slightly more readable if you apply auto reformat in Android Studio